# Shell script to find product of two numbers without using expr and third variable

Tags: ubuntu, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "enter a number"
read a
echo "enter another number"
read b
echo "product of $a and $b is $((a \* b))"
```

Hello, I'm trying to achieve the current question: "Writing shell script to find product of two numbers without using expr and third variable"
I have checked that this could be accomplished using the statement 
    echo "product of $a and $b is `expr $a \* $b`"

The first statement gives an error stating the EOF not found
But , i was curious whether this could also be accomplished without using expr or third variable. Is this possible? or do we have to compulsorily include expr.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If it makes you feel better, that's a terrible error message :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not escape the asterisk inside the arithmetic expression.

```
echo "product of $a and $b is $((a * b))"
```

Comment: Reason being, the contents of an arithmetic expression `$((...))` are subject to different parsing and evaluation rules than a "regular" command. Specifically, there is no pathname expansion inside `$((...))`. `expr "$a" \* "$b"` is correct because `expr` is an ordinary command whose arguments *are* subject to things like pathname expansion.